# Can I get bluetooth devices to remain after suspend/resume and/or reboot

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, bluetooth, suspend

I have recently installed Elementary OS, Loki on a Mac Mini (mid 2010).

I successfully configure a bluetooth keyboard and trackpad (both apple) using the 'System Settings::Bluetooth' panel. Pairing works fine.

If I logout and login, the paired keyboard and trackpad continue to work fine.

If I suspend and resume, Bluetooth has been disabled in the bluetooth panel and in wingpanel.

If I reboot, Bluetooth has been disabled in the bluetooth panel and in wingpanel. (same as suspend resume...but I fear root cause may be different).

To recover, I merely re-enable bluetooh and my devices re-pair.

The frustration is that I cannot use a bluetooh keyboard/trackpad which will not wake the computer from sleep or be unavailable after reboot.

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/524447/cant-enable-bluetooth-on-ubuntu-14-04  work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To enable bluetooth on every startup you need to add your custom command in etc/rc.local

Open terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Now add the following line before exit 0

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

It will start bluetooth on every startup.

Answer (score 1):

In console:

```
bluetoothctl
```

Connect bluetooth device and see in console. Example:

```
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:E1:B3:B7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:E1:B3:B7 ServicesResolved: yes
```

Copy device code. Trust this device:

```
trust 00:1F:20:E1:B3:B7
```

This worked for me.

Source https://pctuner.club/n/2415