# Bluetooth error after suspend

Tags: bluetooth, suspend

I use a Bluetooth mouse, it work fine. After reboot it connects automatic. After suspend it doesn't connect. If I try to do it manually I get this error:

"Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusNotReadyError: Resource Not Ready..."

Waiting didn't solve the problem.

I am a new user and I have tried the solutions I found here ([Can I get bluetooth devices to remain after suspend/resume and/or reboot](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/can-i-get-bluetooth-devices-to-remain-after-suspend-resume-and-or-reboot)) but it didn't work.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

In terminal:

Enter the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file. There you'll find settings for bluetooth. I see that the last line is about AutoEnable, change it to true.

:)
shareimprove this answer

answered Jan 7 '17 at 9:53
Dysproz
7681215

From here: [Bluetooth turns off after reboot](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/bluetooth-turns-off-after-reboot?rq=1)